# Is there a way to edit text documents on the iPhone and sync them with SkyDrive

Tags: iphone, onedrive

I like to keep notes in markdown format in .txt documents.  I have previously used dropbox for this, but have reached my storage limits, and also have had compatibility issues with the dropbox application and some of the security software on my work computer.   I would like to use skydrive for this purpose as I have the free 25GB given to older subscribers, but there seem to be no text editing apps for iPhone that support skydrive.

I'm considering implementing some solution using IFTTT to get text notes into Skydrive, but it requires a file url which seems to eliminate emailing, and while I looked at adding it to dropbox and having it synced to skydrive from there with IFTTT, there doesn't seem to be a way to automatically delete the notes from the public folder once they've been synced.

### Summary

I want to write text notes in markdown on the iPhone, and get them into an appropriate folder on skydrive.  I would prefer a native app solution, but am willing to accept a workaround based on IFTTT or some other service.  I do not want the notes to be available to the public.  Is there a reasonable solution for this problem?

Comment: Doesn't look like SkyDrive supports .txt files http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/skydrive-files/i-cant-open-txt-files-in-skydrive/3971ed80-65f9-4818-98aa-0a542e2abb37?msgId=98cc52dd-244d-426a-951b-2e84714f254d

Comment: That question is related to Office Web Apps.  Skydrive can store any type of file, like dropbox.  It just has special conveniences for images and office files. [Example Text File here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=446DC6255F01A3C3!2062&authkey=!AKkoPiD2VunFg5g)